# Do i have to flush the session or the session variables after the page is submitted?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel app that uses sessions for persisting data between requests(Which is a three page app).After the user has successfully submitted the page or gets to the confirmation page.Is it advisable to flush the session as those session data is not needed or is there any alternative way to handle it?? Is there is any disadvantages if we do not flush the session data??

Comment: Flush on user logout or page leave

Comment: @MahdiYounesi if i do not flush the session.Is there any implications??

Comment: You should use [Flash session data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#flash-data) for this situation.

Comment: Thanku @Gaurav...I was wondering if there is a downside of not flushing out the session data??